# Why was 'with' used instead of 'in' in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

> And I think really especially thinking back to when we were living on Molnár  Road in Kelowna **with** that house, we actually had a yard as well, and we had to sweep,  mop and vacuum in the house.

It would be a really tiny thing but I'm just curious about that. I think **'in'** sounds more natural than **'with'**.
It's really hard to express what I understood about **'with'** in English... but as far as I know, it's like:

> "I met up **with** my friends"
> "a professor **with** expertise teaches me"
> "I broke up the machine **with** a hammer"

and such things like these. Anyway,

Why was **'with'** used instead of **'in'** in this sentence?

Comment: Was the sentence written by a native speaker of English? Certainly _in_, or possibly _at_, would be normal.

Answer (score 1):

This is a run-on sentence. I think the real intention of the speaker was to start a new sentence beginning with "with that house...":

> And I think really especially thinking back to when we were living on Molnár Road in Kelowna. With *that* house, we actually had a yard as well, and we had to sweep, mop and vacuum in the house.

The whole tone seems to be comparing one living situation to another (which would be obvious with more context).

Answer (score 0):

**'In'** or **'at'** should be used in that sentence :

> *And I think really especially thinking back to when we were living on Molnár Road in Kelowna **in** / **at** that house, we actually had a yard as well, and we had to sweep, mop and vacuum in the house.*